# How to disable KMPlayer checking for updates at start up

Tags: updates, kmplayer

How to disable KMPlayer checking for updates always at start up? I'm using version 3.9

It always pops up at startup. Even it's not a direct update, it's going to Cnet downloader when I click ok.

Answer (score 11):

1. Open regedit and navigate to

   > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\KMPlayer\KMP3.0\OptionArea

   and

   > HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4249885587-2716069232-2168524895-1001\Software\KMPlayer\KMP3.0\OptionArea
2. Set `AutoUpdate` to `0`

   ```
   AutoUpdate = dword:00000000 (0)
   ```

Comment: I am using KMPlayer portable, so those keys do not exist in Registry.

Comment: in my case the kmplayer did not play the video nor the sound but it just opened and showed me its black screen, this answer helped in this regard but now it does not let me interact with it in any way

Answer (score 8):

1. Run Notepad as Administrator
2. Go `C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc`
3. Open File `Hosts` (it has no extention) by dragging it onto Notepad
4. Add the following Lines:

   ```
   127.0.0.1  *.kmpmedia.net
   127.0.0.1  *.pandora.tv
   127.0.0.1  cdn.kmplayer.com
   ```
5. Save File and you're done

Comment: Why should I block pandora.tv? Oo

Comment: `127.0.0.1  cdn.kmplayer.com` works at my end. I am using a portable version.

Comment: `127.0.0.1  *.kmpmedia.net` and `127.0.0.1  *.pandora.tv` are not needed at my end.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows open Control Panel and search for 
Change security settings
it will open same windows as Internet Explorer Options Security tab:
Select Restricted sites, click Sites and add there:
*.kmpmedia.net
*.pandora.tv
cdn.kmplayer.com

These will disable Pandora TV, internet site on open.
I think if you want to disable autoupdate feature, just add:
*.kmplayer.com

Answer (score 1):

Version 3.9 doesn't have this option anymore, but at least in version 3.2 you can

1. hit **F2** to open the Preferences
2. Go to *General* -> *When starting...*
3. Uncheck *Check if new version is available*

Comment: It's not like that in 3.9. No such option is there.

Comment: That's what I thought. I will keep my answer for historical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking the connection of KMPlayer works.
But I am not sure what IP is used to check for updates, so I blocked any IP using Windows Firewall

> 1. Control Panel » Windows Firewall
> 2. On left » Advanced settings
> 3. On left » Outbound Rules
> 4. On right - New rule
> 5. New Outbound Rule Wizard
> 6. Rule Type - Custom - Next
> 7. Program - This program path： - Browser - choose file KMPlayer.exe e.g.
>      *C:\The KMPlayer\KMPlayer.exe
>
>      Next*
> 8. Protocol and Ports - Next
> 9. Scope - Next (You can add an IP to the list if you know what IP is used by KMPlayer to check for updates)
> 10. Action - Block the connection - Next
> 11. Profile - Check all - Next
> 12. Name - Type a name -Finish

Answer (score 1):

Go back to 3.3 if possible, I decided to do that after I got sick of the new ad slider and other crap that Pandora packed in with the newest KMPlayer. 3.3 even works with Windows 8 64 bit, which I was worried that it would not work. I will not be upgrading it again since it sold out to Pandora!

Source: Me, I have a laptop with Windows 8.1 64 bit and personally experienced problems with 3.9 also crashing on occasion